# How to write data to the dictionary when the number of elements changes

Tags: python, list, for-loop

```
name = ['Type', 'No.of Cores', 'Section(mm²)']]

table_array = [[[{'Type': '07BN4-AF'}, {'No.of Cores': '1'}, {'Section(mm²)': '1.5-630'}]]
      [{'Type': '07BN4-AF'}, {'No.of Cores': '2、5'}, {'Section(mm²)': '1.0-240'}],
      [[{'Type': '07BN4-AF'}, {'No.of Cores': '3-4'}, {'Section(mm²)': '1.0-300'}]]
     [[{'Type': 'H07RN8-F'}, {'No.of Cores': '2-5'}, {'Section(mm²)': '1.0-6.0'}]]
     [[{'Type': 'TNEFR/TNEFRZ'}, {'No.of Cores': '1'}, {'Section(mm²)': '6-185'}]]
      [{'Type': 'TNEFR/TNEFRZ'}, {'No.of Cores': '2-5'}, {'Section(mm²)': '1.5-150'}],
      [{'Type': 'TNEFR/TNEFRZ'}, {'No.of Cores': '6-24'}, {'Section(mm²)': '1.5-2.5'}]],
     [[{'Type': 'TNEERP/TNEERPZ'}, {'No.of Cores': '1'}, {'Section(mm²)': '6-185'}]]
      [{'Type': 'TNEERP/TNEERPZ'}, {'No.of Cores': '2-5'}, {'Section(mm²)': '1.5-150'}],
      [{'Type': 'TNEERP/TNEERPZ'}, {'No.of Cores': '6-24'}, {'Section(mm²)': '1.5-2.5'}]],
     [[{[{'Type': 'SJYCW-BQ'}, {'No.of Cores': '3、4、5、3+1、3+2'}, {'Section(mm²)': '4-35'}]],
     [[{'Type': 'YCT'}, {'No.of Cores': '3、4、5、3+1、3+2'}, {'Section(mm²)': '4-35'}]]
     [[{[{'Type': 'SJYCR'}, {'No.of Cores': '3、4、5、（3+1）、（3+2）'}, {'Section(mm²)': '4-35'}]]]
```

The function gets 2 variables array with column names (name) of the table and full table content (table_array) (you can find out the number of rows by going through the table_array array). We need to write it in this form

```
template = {
    'parameters_row': row_index,
    'parameters_inf': {
        'row_index': {
            'Type': inf,
            'No.of Cores': inf,
            'Section(mm²)': inf
        },
        'row_index': {
            'Type': inf,
            'No.of Cores': inf,
            'Section(mm²)': inf
        },
        'row_index': {
            'Type': inf,
            'No.of Cores': inf,
            'Section(mm²)': inf
        }
    }
}
```

Maybe there's a feature I'm missing. But the only thing I can think of is to add elements to the array via append)))). But I need to rewrite the array into a dictionary on the contrary

```
for parameters_item in table_array:
    index = 0
    # [[{'Type': '07BN4-AF'}, {'No.of Cores': '1'}, {'Section(mm²)': '1.5-630'}], [{'Type': '07BN4-AF'}, {'No.of Cores': '2、5'}, {'Section(mm²)': '1.0-240'}], [{'Type': '07BN4-AF'}, {'No.of Cores': '3-4'}, {'Section(mm²)': '1.0-300'}]]
    for row in parameters_item:
        # [{'Type': '07BN4-AF'}, {'No.of Cores': '1'}, {'Section(mm²)': '1.5-630'}]
        # [{'Type': '07BN4-AF'}, {'No.of Cores': '2、5'}, {'Section(mm²)': '1.0-240'}]
        # [{'Type': '07BN4-AF'}, {'No.of Cores': '3-4'}, {'Section(mm²)': '1.0-300'}]
        for row_index_item in row:
            parameters_inf = {
                'row_index': {
                    name[index]: row_index_item
                }
            }
            index += 1
```

I'm stuck on the addendum.

Comment: You can't have multiple `'row_index'` keys in the same dictionary.

Comment: The brackets aren't balanced in `table_array`.

Comment: What you probably want is `for key, value in zip(name, parameters_item):`

Comment: Why are all the values in your desired result `inf` instead of the values from `table_array`?

Comment: Since these apparently represent rows, with integer indices, `parameters_inf` should be a list of dictionaries, not a dictionary with duplicate keys (which won't cause a syntax error, but will cause you to overwrite previous values, which is pointless). There's also multiple typos in your shared data. Mismatched brackets and missing commas.

Answer (score 0):

Your example has many syntax errors, however:

```
from pprint import pprint  # getting pretty-printer for nicer looking dict

# assuming that absolute mess of brackets and commas was hiding something like this:
example = [
    [{'Type': '07BN4-AF'}, {'No.of Cores': '1'}, {'Section(mm²)': '1.5-630'}],
    [{'Type': '07BN4-AF'}, {'No.of Cores': '2、5'}, {'Section(mm²)': '1.0-240'}],
    [{'Type': '07BN4-AF'}, {'No.of Cores': '3-4'}, {'Section(mm²)': '1.0-300'}],
    [{'Type': 'H07RN8-F'}, {'No.of Cores': '2-5'}, {'Section(mm²)': '1.0-6.0'}],
    [{'Type': 'TNEFR/TNEFRZ'}, {'No.of Cores': '1'}, {'Section(mm²)': '6-185'}],
    [{'Type': 'TNEFR/TNEFRZ'}, {'No.of Cores': '2-5'}, {'Section(mm²)': '1.5-150'}],
    [{'Type': 'TNEFR/TNEFRZ'}, {'No.of Cores': '6-24'}, {'Section(mm²)': '1.5-2.5'}],
    [{'Type': 'TNEERP/TNEERPZ'}, {'No.of Cores': '1'}, {'Section(mm²)': '6-185'}],
    [{'Type': 'TNEERP/TNEERPZ'}, {'No.of Cores': '2-5'}, {'Section(mm²)': '1.5-150'}],
    [{'Type': 'TNEERP/TNEERPZ'}, {'No.of Cores': '6-24'}, {'Section(mm²)': '1.5-2.5'}],
    [{'Type': 'SJYCW-BQ'}, {'No.of Cores': '3、4、5、3+1、3+2'}, {'Section(mm²)': '4-35'}],
    [{'Type': 'YCT'}, {'No.of Cores': '3、4、5、3+1、3+2'}, {'Section(mm²)': '4-35'}],
    [{'Type': 'SJYCR'}, {'No.of Cores': '3、4、5、（3+1）、（3+2）'}, {'Section(mm²)': '4-35'}]
]

# this turns it into a list of dictionaries
data = [
    {key: value for element in row for key, value in element.items()} 
    for row in example
]

# which looks like this
pprint(data)

# and can be accessed by index like this (printing the 4th, indexed from 0)
pprint(data[3])
```

Output:

```
[{'No.of Cores': '1', 'Section(mm²)': '1.5-630', 'Type': '07BN4-AF'},
 {'No.of Cores': '2、5', 'Section(mm²)': '1.0-240', 'Type': '07BN4-AF'},
 {'No.of Cores': '3-4', 'Section(mm²)': '1.0-300', 'Type': '07BN4-AF'},
 {'No.of Cores': '2-5', 'Section(mm²)': '1.0-6.0', 'Type': 'H07RN8-F'},
 {'No.of Cores': '1', 'Section(mm²)': '6-185', 'Type': 'TNEFR/TNEFRZ'},
 {'No.of Cores': '2-5', 'Section(mm²)': '1.5-150', 'Type': 'TNEFR/TNEFRZ'},
 {'No.of Cores': '6-24', 'Section(mm²)': '1.5-2.5', 'Type': 'TNEFR/TNEFRZ'},
 {'No.of Cores': '1', 'Section(mm²)': '6-185', 'Type': 'TNEERP/TNEERPZ'},
 {'No.of Cores': '2-5', 'Section(mm²)': '1.5-150', 'Type': 'TNEERP/TNEERPZ'},
 {'No.of Cores': '6-24', 'Section(mm²)': '1.5-2.5', 'Type': 'TNEERP/TNEERPZ'},
 {'No.of Cores': '3、4、5、3+1、3+2', 'Section(mm²)': '4-35', 'Type': 'SJYCW-BQ'},
 {'No.of Cores': '3、4、5、3+1、3+2', 'Section(mm²)': '4-35', 'Type': 'YCT'},
 {'No.of Cores': '3、4、5、（3+1）、（3+2）', 'Section(mm²)': '4-35', 'Type': 'SJYCR'}]
{'No.of Cores': '2-5', 'Section(mm²)': '1.0-6.0', 'Type': 'H07RN8-F'}
```